# Show/Hide jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I want a show/hide menu for my website.

I want it to function like the one on [www.nicolaspopupshop.com](http://www.nicolaspopupshop.com) when you click on `"Partners"` at the bottom of the site.

I've tried to do this all day, I'm just so confused at how it works.

I'm pretty good with HTML but once javascript comes into play I'm clueless. I guess this is an annoying question for experts but it would mean the world to me if someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Here is what I have in the style tag:

```
#footer .bottom #partners_trigger {
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-left: 170px; }
    #footer .bottom #partner_list {
      width: 320px;}
    #footer .bottom #partner_list ul {
      position: fixed;
      text-align:center;
      font-size:11px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      bottom: 40px;
      left: 50%;
      width: 320px;
      margin: 0 0 0 -160px;
      background: #FA9313;
      background: rgba(250, 147, 19, 0.85);
      padding: 10px 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
      -moz-border-radius: 6px;
      border-radius: 6px;
      z-index: 300;
      line-height: 18px;
      display: none; }
      #footer .bottom #partner_list ul a {
        color: white; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica;}
      #footer .bottom #partner_list ul a:hover {
        color: #e9118c; }
      #footer .bottom #partner_list ul.active {
        display: block; }
```

I tried to put what I have in the body tag but I can't get it to display properly.

Comment: What you tried till now. Just post some code.

Comment: dude, forget the css. post your html and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $list = $("#your-ul");
    $("#your-toggle-link").bind('click', function() {
       $list.slideToggle();
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however it's still not working for me. I added what's in my style tag to my question, I don't think that'll help too much but it would mean so much to me if you could look it over and suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

First create a div and set its style as display:none. I assume that your Partners link has an id Partners
Then write the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Partners").bind('click', function() {
      $("#your_div").slideToggle(); //your_div is the id of the div with display none
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, however it's still not working for me. I added the code that's in my style tag to my question, not sure if that'll help.